# display all related columns

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I'm using *CakePHP3* for my web. I have two tables, *multimedia* and *description* on different languages, one *multimedia* may have many descriptions and I want to display all descriptions that belong to one *multimedia* but I dont know how.

I already have something to display the *description* but it only shows one *description*, I think *CakePHP* took the primary key from *description* as the foreign key.

**Table Multimedia**

```
id--title--multimedia_id
```

**Table Descriptions**

```
id--description--language_id--multimedia_id
```

On my *PHPMyAdmin* I have this relation: `multimedia_id--multimedia_id`

*MultimediaTable*:

```
        $this->belongsTo('Descriptions', [
        'foreignKey' => 'multimedia_id',
        'bindingKey' => 'multimedia_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```

I use this to display the content:

```
<?= $this->Text->autoParagraph(h($multimedia->description)); ?>
```

When I enter to see my element two I got this:

```html
{
"id": 2,
"description": "A man chooses. A slave obeys",
"multimedia_id": 1
}
```

Comment: foreignkey must relate to a primary key, is multimedia_id in multimedia table a primary key

Comment: I could show descriptions now but only if i use this<?= $this->Text->autoParagraph(h($multimedia)); ?>

Answer (score 0):

I only need to use this when I want to print:

```
foreach($multimedia->descriptions as $description ) {
  print_r ($description->description);
  echo "<br>";
  echo "<br>";
}
```